# Why can't Google Maps static API handle my encoded URIs?

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm trying to integrate some Google maps bits into my Java web app using the Google Maps static API.  For the moment I'm just trying to get a map, any map.  Their example:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

works fine from my browser.  However the Java HTTP client software I am using (the one from Apache's http components, version 4.0.2) insists that I encode my URIs, so I end up with this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center%3D40.714728%2C-73.998672%26zoom%3D12%26size%3D400x400%26sensor%3Dfalse
```

which doesn't work.  I would happily not encode my URIs but the Apache client fails if I don't.  So my question is how can I either:

- persuade Apache's client to use the plain URI or
- get the encoded URI into a form Google will accept

?

Comment: You need to encode the URI *components* instead of the whole thing. The `&` and `=` characters need to remain unencoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pekka suggested you need to leave to `&` and `=` unencoded.

Your encoded url

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center%3D40.714728%2C-73.998672%26zoom%3D12%26size%3D400x400%26sensor%3Dfalse
```

vs unencoded `&` (`%26`) and `=` (`%3D`) (working)

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728%2C-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

Apache's HTTPComponents HTTP Client has a lot of interfaces with which you can build your request URL. To make sure that the proper parts of the URL are encoded I would suggest using this method:

```
List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("center", "40.714728,-73.998672"));
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zoom", "12"));
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("size", "400x400"));
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sensor", "false"));
URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "maps.google.com", -1, "/maps/api/staticmap", 
    URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"), null);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

1. More example http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html
2. API Docs http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html

Comment: Just simple rule, always encode param name and value. adamse have given a nice example.

Answer (score 1):

Only encode the parameters of the URI. Your first `?`, then your `=` and your `&` shouldn't be URI encoded.

Your URI should be

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728%2C-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

The only URI-encoded character is `%2C`, the `,` between your coordinates.

Comment: What I don't understand: why does Google not support the necessary encoding of `&` to `&amp;` in its url? The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate-by-input) marks those with `&` as invalid.